# What is this MEV tx trying to achieve?

Tags: flashbots, mev, mev-boost

For this TX:  https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8b0351a83e453e30a8b4ada8adc1ce42dac73c05bc2ba87304906f1eed8a77a2

Seems PunkOTC sent 7 ETH to mev bot and mev bot sent this 7ETH to (Lido: Execution Layer Rewards Vault)
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaa9e2d2d17b4dc58fc3cfff90410bc4e49d60e3bd27c9961678250aecb55471b

I failed to understand what was his purpose. Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 0):

It's purpose is to ensure that excessive fees are not charged to the sender via slippage, similar to RookFi protocol.

Answer (score 0):

first we have to answer some questions:

1-what is LIDO? lido.fi is a project that helps you to participate in Ethereum (or another network) validation and get their reward.

2-why is this using MEV bot? MEV bots prevent front running, back running and sandwich attacks, they are used by protocols to send transactions to validators without observing in mempool.

in conclusion, user send 7 ETH to lido to participate in the validation and get the reward without being visible in mempool.